# Exclude blank cells from formula while adding formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using this formula to concatenate the contents of several cells into a single cell:

```
=B2 & " - " & F2 & G2 & " - " & H2
```

However, F2, G2, and H2 may sometimes be blank. Here's how my concatenated cell looks when all of those cells have values:

B2 content - F2 content G2 content - H2 content

and here's how it looks if F2 and G2 have no data:

B2 content -  - H2 content

How I can I set up the formula so that the extra dashes and spaces would be hidden in that second example, leaving me with "B2 content - H2 content"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Code:

```
=IF(B2="","",B2&" - ")&IF(F2="","",F2&" - ")&IF(G2="","",G2&" - ")&IF(H2="","",H2)
```

Comment: Thanks, @Jatin and M.Awais, that worked. Here is my final formula (which included another adjacent cell):

Comment: =IF(B2="","",B2)&IF(E2="",""," - "&E2)&IF(F2="","",F2)&IF(G2="",""," - "&G2)&IF(H2="",""," - "&H2)

Comment: E and F are now the "middle" content. G is always preceded with a dash if G has a value, and H is always preceded with a dash if H has a value.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(F2 & G2<>"",B2&" - "&F2&G2&" - "&H2,B2 & " - " & H2)
```